# Read iframe url paramters inside button click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have to use one of my html page as an iframe in some other site (not in same domain. need to use it like a widget.) In my iframe url there are some parameters

ex: < **iframe src="www.MyTestSite.com/Home.html?id=3"** width="800" height="300">< /iframe>

The html page I'm using as the iframe (www.MyTestSite.com/Home.html?id=3) has a button and in that button click function i need to read that "id" parameters value. But if i use window.location.href for read it I'm unable to read that value since the iframe loaded in some other page (other domain ex: **www.example.com/index.html**)

Is there any way to get that iframe url query string value inside onlick function? My page only display as an iframe not as a whole page and in some different domain too.

(What i want is, to read that iframe url "id" parameter inside a button click function. iframe loads in some other domain page. So when ever i use window.location.href i dont get my iframe url. The button i mentioned about contained in y iframe page. when ever i click that button i need to read that "id" parameter)

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can open a different url page using `window.open()` just in case might be useful.

Comment: @MrNew - you mean before i read the parameter value should reopen the page in another tab..?

Comment: Hm I can't answer with a code because its been marked as duplicate, but you can create your button `<button onclick="getSrc(iframeId)"></button>` then create that function and pass that `iframeId` argument in the function then do `var getSrc = document.getElementById('your-iframe-id"); alert(getSrc.src)` this should give you the iframe Url but its probably not the best as it targets specific `id` https://plnkr.co/edit/GI5rho44Ik3DfJlYKk5x?p=preview

Comment: @MrNew Thank you for the reply. Actually this is not a duplicate question. i checked their solutions as well. They are about set url parameters from server side. that's not what i want here.


<html> 
 <head> 
   <script>
 function myFunction() {
  //in here i want to read "id" parameter
 }
   </script>
 </head>  
 <body> 
 <input type="text" id="txtName" />    
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>    
 </body>
</html>

Comment: create a new question if its not a duplicate otherwise people can't show code as their answer then comment back here so people can see your new question.